# Getting Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. error in spite of referencing router moudule

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular2-routing, kendo-ui-angular2, angular4-router

I am implementing basic routing in my angular 4 application and getting the following error when loading the application on the browser. I have defined the routes in approuting.module as also referenced the router module in Ngmodule as well approuting.module. Not sure what the problem is

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("ew" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleView">
                                                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/view', dataItem.movieId, 'responses']" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-fil"): ng:///MovieModule/MovieComponent.html@85:59
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("it" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleEdit">
                                                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['edit', dataItem.movieId]" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidd"): ng:///MovieModule/MovieComponent.html@92:59
```

Below is the source code of my application

**snippet of the kendo grid in movie.component.html**

```
  </kendo-grid-column>
                                             <kendo-grid-column title="View" headerClass="kendoGridHeader" class="kendoGridControlCell">
                                                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                                                    <span data-title="View" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleView">
                                                        <a [routerLink]="['/view', dataItem.movieId, 'responses']" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                    </span>
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </kendo-grid-column>
                                            <kendo-grid-column title="Edit" headerClass="kendoGridHeader" class="kendoGridControlCell">
                                                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                                                    <span data-title="Edit" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleEdit">
                                                        <a [routerLink]="['edit', dataItem.movieId]" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                    </span>
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </kendo-grid-column>
                                            <kendo-grid-column title="Delete" headerClass="kendoGridHeader" class="kendoGridControlCell">
                                                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                                                    <span data-title="Delete" [hidden]="!dataItem.isVisibleDelete">
                                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu table-popup-delete">
                                                            <li>Are you sure you want to delete this?</li>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <li><button class="button" (click)="deleteWorkflow(dataItem.movieId)" style="width:100%;">Delete</button></li>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <li><button class="button" style="width:100%;">Cancel</button></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </span>
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </kendo-grid-column>
```

**approuting.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie/movie.component';
import {HomeComponent}  from '../app/home/home.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {NewmovieComponent} from './movie/new/newmovie.component';
import {EditmovieComponent} from './movie/edit/editmovie.component';
import {ViewmovieComponent} from './movie/view/viewmovie.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path : '', component : HomeComponent},
{path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent},
{path : 'new' , component : NewmovieComponent },
{path : 'edit' , component : EditmovieComponent },
{path : 'view' , component : ViewmovieComponent },
{path: '**',component : NotFoundComponent}

];

@NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
     exports: [RouterModule]

})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './approuting.module';
import {HomeModule} from './home/home.module';
import {MovieModule} from './movie/movie.module';
import { MRDBCommonService } from './shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    NotFoundComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    MovieModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants,
              MRDBCommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try moving `BrowserModule` to the top of imports? Or at least above the `AppRoutingModule`.

Comment: That didnt help

Comment: Your code looks correct, make sure everything is actually compiled properly, I would stop all `ng serve` or `ng build -w` and `rd /s /q node_modules` (or `rm -rf node_modules` if on Linux), and then `npm i` and see

Comment: Tried exactly what you suggested but still giving the same problem. Looks like the link is not correctly getting built

Comment: Please note the page loads if I comment only the anchor tags

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i have managed to fix the issue. I had to add the routermodule to the imports of the moviemodule is the routerlinks are referred in the moviemodule

Answer (score 3):

**Import RouterModule**

> import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    LayoutComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Just import the RouterModule similar to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my case that is slightly different. Maybe it can help someone else.

As everybody explained in all posts I found...

AppRoutingModule:

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
```

Others routing modules:

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forChildren(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
```

Home module has a template with routerLink:

```
<a [routerLink]="'asdf'">asdf</a>
```

Below is the situation in which the **error** has occurred. Note that app is lazy-loading others modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home-routing.module')
            .then(m => m.HomeRoutingModule) //**wrong!**
  }
]
```

This is the situation how it was **solved**, because I was **importing the wrong module**:

App is lazy-loading others modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module')
            .then(m => m.HomeModule)
  }
]
```