# Angular 7 and can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular7

I am creating a new Angular 7 app and I have been researching this problem for the last few days, but I unable to find a solution to this error:

> can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Here are some of the articles I have looked at [Angular2 Exception: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317044/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-pro) and [Getting Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. error in spite of referencing router moudule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168952/getting-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-a-error) but "no-go".

Here is the layout:

app -> navigation
Here is the code:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UltiMaterialModule } from './ulti-material/ulti-material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { NavigationModule } from './navigation/navigation.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UltiMaterialModule, // ulti-nav/ulti-nav.component.ts
    NavigationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '**',  loadChildren: './navigation/navigation.module#NavigationModule', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
```

navigation/navigation.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RouterModule, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { UltiMaterialModule } from '../ulti-material/ulti-material.module';

import { VendorsComponent } from '../vendors/vendors.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserPanelComponent } from '../user-panel/user-panel.component';
import { QuestionnaireComponent } from '../questionnaire/questionnaire.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation.component';

import { NavigationRoutingModule } from './navigation-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VendorsComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    UserPanelComponent,
    QuestionnaireComponent,
    NavigationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    UltiMaterialModule,
    NavigationRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavigationComponent,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class NavigationModule {}
```

navigation/navigation-router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { VendorsComponent } from '../vendors/vendors.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';

export const NavigationRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'vendors', component: VendorsComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(NavigationRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class NavigationRoutingModule {}
```

navigation/navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {
  Router,
  Event as RouterEvent,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError
} from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {

  // Native Template fails on Button mat-icon render with always false. Had to reconstruct based on:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525676/angular-6-material-nav-component-template-parse-errors-unexpected-token?rq=1
  /*
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );
  */

  isHandset$: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);

  _loading = true;
  public get showLoadingIndicator() {
    return this._loading;
  }
  public set showLoadingIndicator(value) {
    this._loading = value;
  }

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {

    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(event);
    });
  }

  // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this._loading = true;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this._loading = false;
    }

    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this._loading = false;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this._loading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

navigation.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showLoadingIndicator" class="loading-indicator"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button 
      type="button"
      aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
      mat-icon-button
      (click)="drawer.toggle()"
      *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span><mat-icon class="logo" svgIcon="logo2"></mat-icon></span>
    <span class="span-fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <span>Global Security Research Project System</span>
    <button 
      type="button"
      aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
      mat-icon-button
      (click)="user.toggle()"
      *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="false"
    fixedTopGap="64"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item >
        <mat-icon class="icon">home</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Home</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item >
        <mat-icon class="developer_board">developer_board</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Project</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item >
        <mat-icon class="how_to_reg">how_to_reg</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Products</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon class="people">people</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Teams</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerlink]="['/vendors']" routerLinkActive>
        <mat-icon class="store">store</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Vendors</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon class="dashboard">dashboard</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
      <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon class="question_answer">question_answer</mat-icon>
        <span class="label">Questionnaire</span>
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav 
    #user
    position="end">
    <app-user-panel></app-user-panel>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="material-page-spacing">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

package.json - dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/core": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/http": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/material": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/router": "^7.0.2",
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^5.0.2",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
```

I am at a loss on what the problem is. I have the proper imports and exports from what I can tell. If you see something that I cannot please feel free to comment.

If you need more information, such as more code, also please let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property `routerLink` is case sensitive.

> change **[routerlink]** to **[routerLink]**

```
[routerLink]="['/vendors']"
```

Comment: Wow,  can't believe I did not see that. That fixed the problem. My mistake

Comment: I did not down vote you. I tried to up vote you but my reputation does not allow me to

Comment: Also, if you pass a constant string, you don't need brackets: `routerLink="/vendors"`

Answer (score 15):

For those people who have `routerLink` camel cased correctly and are still getting the same error, you probably have not imported `RouterModule` inside the module that defines your component.

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
   declarations:[YourComponents],
   imports:[RouterModule]
...
```

Comment: This helped a lot to my case. Good Point.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error "Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'button' ".

Adding the module RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]) to the spec class solved my issue.